# android implement xmppconnection service

Tags: android, service, xmpp, asmack

I am trying to create a basic chat app using asmack and Openfire. 
I have created a bound service for the XMPPConnection and each Activity binds to it.

Whenever I try to bind to a Service there is a very long delay. I know that the bindService is asynchronous but I want to be certain that my implementation of the Service is correct before I begin looking elsewere for problems.

I bind my Service in the onCreate method and try to access the connection in the onStart.

I am still new to this but I suspect that I have done something wrong thread-wise. The way my app runs now, the mBound variable returns true only if I try to access it from an OnClickListener. What is it that happens in the Listener that makes such a big difference? I tried to find the code for the OnClick method but I couldn't find it.

My XMPPConnectionService is this:

package com.example.smack_text;

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class XMPPService extends Service{

XMPPConnection connection;
//  private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


@Override
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
Log.d("service","created");
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
Log.d("sevice","bound");
LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder (this);
return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
XMPPService service;

public LocalBinder (XMPPService service)
{
this.service = service;
}

public XMPPService getService (){
return service;
}

//          XMPPService getService() {
//              return XMPPService.this;
//          }
}

public void connect(final String user, final String pass) {
Log.d("Xmpp Alex","in service");

ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("10.0.2.2",5222);

//          KEYSTORE SETTINGS
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
config.setTruststorePassword(null);
config.setTruststorePath(null);
} 
else {
config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
if (path == null)
path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
       + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
       + "cacerts.bks";
    config.setTruststorePath(path);
} 

//          Create XMPP Connection

connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

try {
connection.connect();
connection.login(user, pass);
if(connection.isConnected()){
Log.d("Alex", "connected biatch!");
}
else{
Log.d("Alex","not connected");
}


} catch (XMPPException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}).start();
}
public void disconnect(){
if(connection.isConnected()){
connection.disconnect();
}  
else{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I implement an Android Chat with Asmack.

I have created a Service.
The service has a global variable with the XmppConnection.
At the begining i use the thread for connect and login. 
then I set VCard for logged user, set rosterListener
finally set `connection.addPacketListener` 
I update the activities with a BroadcastReceiver activity side and

```
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return mBinderXmpp;
    }

    public class BinderServiceXmpp extends Binder {
        ServiceXmpp getService() {
            return ServiceXmpp.this;
        }
    }


    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayInfo();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); // 2 segundos
        }
    };
    private void DisplayInfo() {
        isRunning = true; // flag to know if service is running
        Intent tempIntent;
        tempIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        tempIntent.putExtra("UPDATE_OPTION", UPDATE_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(tempIntent);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation works, you still need to implement the handler for the actions like CONNECT and DISCONNECT from your clients bound (LoginActivity for instance).

Example:

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler { // Handler of incoming messages from clients bound.
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_CONNECT_XMPP:
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Do connection
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        // Notify the connection status
                    }
                }.execute();
                break;
            case MSG_DICCONNECT_XMPP:
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Do disconnection
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        // Notify the connection status
                    }
                }.execute();

                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

But, this approach of creating an AsyncTask anytime the Service needs to run a network action will reach its limit for the sendBroadcast in a BroadcastReceiver.

If you have BroadcastReceiver that needs to start or stop the connection by sending a message to the XMPPService, you have something like this:

```
public class NetworkConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo network = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        network = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (XmppService.isRunning() && network.isConnected()) {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(XmppService.ACTION_CONNECT));
        } else if (XmppService.isRunning() && !network.isConnected()) {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(XmppService.ACTION_DISCONNECT));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you will need to implement a Broadcast listener in the XmppService class.
But, you CANNOT run an AsyncTask in a Broadcast listener!

The remain options are described in my post here:

[Android - Best option to implement Networking Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929952/anroid-best-option-to-implement-networking-class/19990937#19990937)