# Best option to implement Networking Class

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, xmpp

I am starting a project that will access a Xmpp server in the background.
It will maintain the connection alive and reconnect when required + do other Xmpp things.

I want to implement a class to do the work. 
The class will have to interact with other `Services` (`Location`...), and `BroadcastReceivers` (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ....).
Basically, Activities and Broadcast receivers will ask the Xmpp Class to start an action like: CONNECT, DISCONNECT, RECONNECT, JOIN CHAT, SEND MESSAGE etc.

First approach is to implement it as a `Service` but a service runs in the main thread so the implementation is wrong.

Secondly, I wanted to make it as an `IntentService` because the `onHandleIntent` is run async and then I am out of the main thread.

But the `onHandleIntent` is run only once to perform an async task. So,
if I want an `Activity` to perform another "action", I can only send a broadcast event and I will fall in the main thread problem again.
Also, `IntentService` is not really aimed to be 'live' all the time.

In the Google documentation, they say you need to run `AsyncTask` for each network access ... is this the only way to make a network access ... this is pretty sad.

I had a look on the implementation in the GTalkSMS and they seemed to have the same problem. Actually they use a `Service` with a `ServiceHandler` management like this:

> ```
> // some stuff for the async service implementation - borrowed heavily from
> // the standard IntentService, but that class doesn't offer fine enough
> // control for "foreground" services.
> private static volatile Looper sServiceLooper;
> private static volatile ServiceHandler sServiceHandler;
>
> private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
>     public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
>         super(looper);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>         onHandleIntent((Intent) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the only way to do so is to create a service that has its own thread.

Vogella website describes a way to setup the Service in the AndroidManifest: 
["4. Services in separate processes"](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#service_binding)

```
<service
  android:name="WordService"
  android:process=":my_process" 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/service_name"
  >
</service>
```

The alternative is to do a Service Handler manually as I described in my initial post like this:

```
public class XmppService extends Service {

    public final static String ACTION_CONNECT = "action.CONNECT";
    public final static String ACTION_DISCONNECT = "action.DISCONNECT";

    // some stuff for the async service implementation - borrowed heavily from
    // the standard IntentService, but that class doesn't offer fine enough
    // control for "foreground" services.
    private static volatile Looper sServiceLooper;
    private static volatile ServiceHandler sServiceHandler;
    private long mHandlerThreadId;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            onHandleIntent((Intent) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The IntentService(-like) implementation manages taking the intents passed
     * to startService and delivering them to this function which runs in its
     * own thread 
     *
     * @param intent
     * @param id
     */
    void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent, int id) {
        // ensure XMPP manager is setup (but not yet connected)
        if (Thread.currentThread().getId() != mHandlerThreadId) {
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
        }

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(XmppService.ACTION_CONNECT)){
            // Do Connect
        }
        else if(action.equals(XmppService.ACTION_DISCONNECT)){
            // Do Disconnect
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Start a new thread for the service
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(SERVICE_THREAD_NAME);
        thread.start();
        mHandlerThreadId = thread.getId();
        sServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        sServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(sServiceLooper);

    }
}
```